# Is the following a suitable question for TeX.SE?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have an idea for a question, but it's rather non-standard, so I thought I'd check here whether it's suitably on-topic to post.

**Title.** "Find-the-error puzzles in LaTeX!"

**Answer.** For a bit of fun, and maybe some pedagogical benefit too, each answer to this question contains a *short* LaTeX document that gives a compilation error. The challenge is to try and spot the error *without compiling* - just by reading the code. And of course, no giving solutions in the comments!

**Sample answer.**
Difficulty rating 3/5.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\startpoint{1,1}
\newcommand\endpoint{3,3}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[red] (\startpoint) -- (\endpoint);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Somewhat related (on the main site): [Documents with typical LaTeX errors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33468/5764)

Comment: Have a look at [What would you like to read in a TeX.SX blog?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1460/15717)

Answer (score 19):

It's a nice idea, it's fun, we can learn from it. However, I think this question is not suitable for TeX.SE.

From the [FAQ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/faq):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the
>   usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

This question would be wecome in an open forum such as on [LaTeX-Community.org](http://latex-community.org/forum). I promise I would join such a topic there ;-) I understand, that you would like to talk about with users from *here*. Well, one possibility: start the action in that forum, mention it in the TeX.SE chat or right here in this meta topic, or link in a related real question on the main site.

Comment: Another possibility is to start a new series in our blog. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda That could be fun `:)`. Could you tell me a little about how might that work?

Comment: @JohnWickerson Follow chat link in [Posting an article to the blog](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1892/15717). But i have to agree with [charles stewart comment](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1694/the-prominent-link-to-tex-blogoverflow-com-has-been-buried/1695#comment4369_1695):) at [The prominent link to tex.blogoverflow.com has been buried](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1694/15717). Also  [Nicola Talbot](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/19862/nicola-talbot) today suggested [same issue in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9611301#9611301)

Comment: @JohnWickerson: I'm not sure how it might work. `:)` A possible approach would be a nice blog post with some introductory text, the code, some explanations on why the code doesn't work and the solution. I think the post should be self-contained, that is, everything should be in place (code and answer). The series could be something along the lines of *Spot the error*. `:)` We could get feedback from all other bloggers as well, so we could come up with a nice format.